# Is there a markup language for writing stage plays?

Tags: playwriting, markup-languages

Is there an equivalent of the [Fountain markup language](https://fountain.io) for theatre plays rather than film scripts?

Comment: Is there any reason why Fountain would not work for stage plays? Some missing feature?

Comment: There are lots of tools for Fountain, some listed [here](https://fountain.io/apps). At least one mentions theatre scripts. It would also help if you specified the OS/platform you want (Windows, Mac, iOS, Android, etc) as I assume a markup language with no formatting tool would be pretty useless.

Comment: I guess the issue with using Fountain is less the markup language itself than getting an output that matches a stage-play format rather than a screenplay format (hence the tools I mention above). However there are several stage-play formats so you might want to indicate which you want.

Comment: @StuartF I will take a look at those tools thank you